# Unbounded family of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Definitions:

1. For functions $f,g:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$, we say $f\leq ^{*} g$ if there exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $n\leq m$ we have $f(m)\leq g(m)$
2. Family $F$ of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is **unbounded** if for every function $g:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$, exist $f\in F$ such that $f\leq ^{*} g$ isn't holds.

Question:

> Show that an unbounded family $F$ of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to
>   $\mathbb{N}$ is  uncountable.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is there a reason you posted the same question again? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243044/family-of-unbounded-functions-is-uncountable

Comment: I don't think this question is really a duplicate of the other question. See also my post in the [meta thread for reopen request](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc/18944#18944) to see more details.

Comment: Another way to reformulate this question: It is asking for the proof that the $\mathfrak b\ge\aleph_1$, where $\mathfrak b$ denotes the [bounding number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of showing that every unbounded family is uncountable, let's try the (equivalent) contraposition: Show that every countable family fails to be unbounded.
Let $F$ be a countable family of functions $\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$.
That is, there exists a bijection $\mathbb N\to F$, or simply put, we can enumerate the elements of $F$ like this:
$$\tag1F=\{f_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}.$$
This $F$ would be unbounded if for every $g\colon\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ there exists an $f\in F$ such that $f\le^* g$ is false.
Thus we have to show that there exists $g\colon\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$ such that for all $f\in F$ the statement $f\le^* g$ is true.

Simply define
$$\tag2g(n)=\max\{f_k(n)\mid k\le n\}.$$
Now let $f$ be an arbitrary element of $F$.
We have to show $f\le^* g$.
By $(1)$, we have $f=f_n$ for some $n$.
Then using $(2)$ 
$$\tag3g(m)=\max\{f_k(m)\mid k\le m\}\ge f(m)\quad \text{for }m\ge n$$
because $f$ occurs among the $f_k$ with $k\le m$.
But $(3)$ is just the definition of $f\le^* g$. $_\square$

Comment: Can you elaborate, because what you wrote appears as a hint to the problem?

Comment: I thought I was very verbose!?

Comment: Thank you so much, Gold medalist! :)

Comment: I know this is an old question/answer, but I have a related question: why doesn't the above argument also apply to an uncountable family of sets? I know you can't use N as an index set in that case, but could you use an uncountable set as an index set and define a function similar to g(n) which takes the max value across an uncountable family of functions?